# Delete first 10 lines only for some files

Tags: python, r, bash

I'm currently analyzing files given in output from a pipeline. I'm working with csv files which structure is:

```
sample,acc,count
https//:url0.com,LS4456,10
https//:url1.com,LS4465,15
```

The problem is that the pipeline for some files (actually a lot of them) when cannot find a certain file puts ten rows before the csv formatted part as log:

```
some useless log information... 1
some useless log information... 2
some useless log information... 3
some useless log information... 4
some useless log information... 5
some useless log information... 6
some useless log information... 7
some useless log information... 8
some useless log information... 9
sample,acc,count
https//:url0.com,LS4456,10
https//:url1.com,LS4465,15
```

I have  274 files, some of them have the log part, others don't. Is there an efficient way to remove the first 10 lines of the files with the log part using R, python or bash?

The basic idea is:
Open file;
**If** the first word is not "sample" **then** delete the first 9 rows

Comment: Could you also add sample code that has already failed? And perhaps use only one language. Otherwise, this is too broad since it requests for a solution in multiple languages

Comment: I actually did nothing at all, those files are on my university server and I'm to afraid to do anything until I'm sure I'm not deleting any files (the server with 140 cores used a month to create them)

Comment: So you just want to match the word `log` in a file and delete that line? Or is log an actual log?

Comment: The basic idea is: go through all files, if the first word is not `sample` delete the first 9 rows

Comment: Check out `head` and `tail`, they should solve your problems. At least with a combination of those two and a Unix pipe in between. ;)

Comment: This can be improved(perhaps to use `head` since this can match sample anywhere in the file): `sed -i '1,9d' "$(ls | xargs grep -iP '^sample' -l)"`. `ls` because I made some dummy directory to play around with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) fread** Using the file Minardi.csv which we generate reproducibly in the Note at the end, use the data.table `fread` function which accepts a string for `skip` such that all lines prior to the first occurrence of that string are skipped.  Omit the `data.table=FALSE` argument if it is ok to return a data.table.

```
library(data.table)
fread("Minardi.csv", skip = "sample", data.table = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
            sample    acc count
1 https//:url0.com LS4456    10
2 https//:url1.com LS4465    15
```

**1a)** If the junk lines do not contain any commas then this alternative also works:

```
fread("Minardi.csv", sep = ",", data.table = FALSE)
```

**2) Base R**  A base R solution is:

```
read.csv("Minardi.csv", as.is = TRUE,
   skip = if (grepl("sample", readLines("Minardi.csv", 1))) 0 else 9)
```

**2a)** If the junk lines contain no commas then this also works:

```
# Windows
read.csv(pipe("findstr , Minardi.csv"), as.is = TRUE)

# Linux
read.csv(pipe("grep , Minardi.csv"), as.is = TRUE)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "some useless log information... 1
some useless log information... 2
some useless log information... 3
some useless log information... 4
some useless log information... 5
some useless log information... 6
some useless log information... 7
some useless log information... 8
some useless log information... 9
sample,acc,count
https//:url0.com,LS4456,10
https//:url1.com,LS4465,15"

writeLines(Lines, "Minardi.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  It removes any records with the word 'some' in them.

```
# Create dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = c(
    'some useless log information... 1',
    'some useless log information... 2',
    'some useless log information... 3',
    'some useless log information... 4',
    'some useless log information... 5',
    'some useless log information... 6',
    'some useless log information... 7',
    'some useless log information... 8',
    'some useless log information... 9',
    'sample,acc,count',
    'https//:url0.com,LS4456,10',
    'https//:url1.com,LS4465,15'
      ))

# Keep only records that do not contain 'some'
df <- subset(df, regexpr(pattern ='some',df$x1) == -1)
```

Comment: Since the post does not specify any language / library for the task, it would be better to explain the necessary setup to run the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to get list of all files in directory excluding subdirectories. To delete first lines from file you should rewrite it. That's why firstly we use `file.readlines()` to read content of file into list. Then we use `file.writelines()` to write **sliced** list into file. We find index of first line which starts from `"sample"` and slice source list from this line. If you're sure that it'll always be 9 lines you can replace it with `f.writelines(lines[10:])`.

**Code:**

```
import os

path, _, files = next(os.walk("./sample"))
for fn in files:
    with open(os.path.join(path, fn)) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open(os.path.join(path, fn), "w") as f:
        f.writelines(lines[next(i for i, line in enumerate(lines) if line.startswith("sample")):])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using R, you can first get the path of all the files

```
all_files <- list.files("/path/of/the/files", full.names = TRUE)
```

Loop over them, read each file with `header = FALSE` check if first cell contains word `"sample"`. If it does then delete first 9 lines and write it back.

```
lapply(all_files, function(x) {
    df <- read.csv(x, header = FALSE)
    if (df[1, 1] != "sample") {
      df <- df[10:nrow(df), ]
      write.csv(df, x, row.names = FALSE)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to check the validity:

```
awk 'NR==1 && !($0 ~ /^sample/) {skip=1} skip != 1 || NR >= 10 {print}' file.txt
```